# Extjs MessageBox override so buttons are aligned to right instead of center (Extjs 4.2)

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I have looked through the messagebox.js source code and I see that when the docked toolbar for the buttons are created it has the code:

```
me.bottomTb = new Ext.toolbar.Toolbar({
        id: baseId + '-toolbar',
        ui: 'footer',
        dock: 'bottom',
        layout: {
            pack: 'center'
        },
        items: [
            me.msgButtons[0],
            me.msgButtons[1],
            me.msgButtons[2],
            me.msgButtons[3]
        ]
    });
```

which aligns the buttons to the center of the window. However, for consistency through my app I would like these buttons to be aligned to the right instead. I would like to be able to do this without overwriting the source code. I have an override file for message box and was trying to override the initComponent function but without luck so far.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you override the layout in the above code?

Comment: I am not sure how to access just the layout. I tried override the initComponent function (which has the layout). But that seems like overkill and has conflicting ids

Comment: Try this https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/eni&view/editor

Answer (score 0):

Get the reference to the button toolbar by calling `getDockedItems` on `Ext.MessageBox`.

```
var buttonTb = Ext.MessageBox.getDockedItems('toolbar')[0];
```

Then set the `layout.pack` config to `end` and the buttons will appear on the right side.

```
buttonTb.layout.pack = "end";
```

A good place to change this config is in the `beforerender` event of the `Ext.MessageBox`.
See the full code and the working [Sencha Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1tku).

```
Ext.MessageBox.on('beforerender', function(messageBox) {
    var buttonTb = messageBox.getDockedItems('toolbar')[0];
    buttonTb.layout.pack = "end";
});

Ext.MessageBox.show({
    title: "My aligned MessageBox",
    msg: "test",
    buttons: Ext.Msg.YES
});
```